# NSString - how to check if it contains quotation marks <">

Tags: objective-c

[[somestring substringtoindex:0] is equaltostring:@"""]; 'makes red' the rest of the code. actually i can't put quotation marks inside quotation marks. still, this is the character i want to reffer. how should I do it in the correct way?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape a character, use the backslash.

```
@"\"";
```

And to check if a string exists, use `-rangeOfString:`.

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"\""].location != NSNotFound) { ... }
```

or `-hasPrefix:` and `-hasSuffix:`

```
if ([string hasPrefix:@"\""]) { ... }
```